# How to execute multiple times a couroutine without stopping it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have an array of gameobjects that are lights, I'm trying to increase and drecrease range size of a point light over time, problem is lights some times doesn't decrease over time, they just go to range 0 instantly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] stars;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ChooseStar());
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }


    IEnumerator IncreaseRadius(GameObject star, float duration)
    {
        Debug.Log("Increasing: "+star.name + " radius: " + star.GetComponent<Light>().range);
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            star.GetComponent<Light>().range = counter;
            yield return null;
        }
        StartCoroutine(DecreaseRadius(star));
    }

    IEnumerator DecreaseRadius(GameObject star)
    {
        Debug.Log("Decreasing: "+star.name+" radius: "+ star.GetComponent<Light>().range);
        float counter = star.GetComponent<Light>().range;

        while (star.GetComponent<Light>().range >= 0f)
        {
            counter -= Time.deltaTime;
            star.GetComponent<Light>().range = counter;
            yield return null;
        }
        star.GetComponent<Light>().range = 0f;

    }

    IEnumerator ChooseStar()
    {
        float duration = Random.Range(3, 8);
        float waitTime = 2f;

        GameObject choosenStar = stars[Random.Range(0, stars.Length)];

        if (choosenStar.GetComponent<Light>().range <= 0f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(IncreaseRadius(stars[Random.Range(0, stars.Length)], duration));
        }
        else
        {
            waitTime = 0f;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        StartCoroutine(ChooseStar());

    }
}
```

the expected result should be this sequence:

1 - pick random star from array of gameobjects
2 - check if the star alredy is being range increased, if yes start again to search a new one if no starts to increase.
3 - light starts increasing until duration, then call decrease function
4 - star starts to decrease, when function is over it reset range to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in general: You can simply put a

```
while (true)
{
   ... 

   yield return ...
}
```

around your code. As long as you `yield` somewhere inside it that's totally valid for Coroutines.

---

My guess would be that you get concurrent Coroutines because you don't wait for `IncreaseRadius` to finish before choosing the next random star ... which could be the same as before.

```
if (chosenStar.range <= 0f)
{
    StartCoroutine(IncreaseRadius(stars[Random.Range(0, stars.Length)], duration));
}
else
{
    waitTime = 0f;
}
```

also you do a Random.Range here again although you have already choosen another star before, was this intended?

---

First in general instead of using `GetComponent<Light>` all the time over and over again rather simply make

```
public Light[] stars;
```

reference the object just in the same way as before but now you are directly dealing with the `Light` references instead of `GameObject`.

Then you know that

```
float duration = Random.Range(3, 8);
```

actually returns random full `int` values between `3` and `7`. If you rather wanted to have `float` values also between `3` and `8` so also including e.g. `3.253453f` then you should rather use

```
var duration = Random.Range(3.0f, 8.0f);
```

#### Solution 1 - Only one star at a time

As simple alternative you could always animate only one star at a time. You can achieve this by `yield return` another `IEnumerator`. That make the other `IEnumerator` execute and at the same time waits for it to finish. Something like

```
public Light[] stars;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(ChooseStar());
}

private IEnumerator IncreaseRadius(Light star, float duration)
{
    Debug.Log("Increasing: " + star.name + " radius: " + star.range);
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        star.range = counter;
        yield return null;
    }

    // again do the decreasing and at the same time wait for it to finish
    yield return DecreaseRadius(star);
}

private static IEnumerator DecreaseRadius(Light star)
{
    Debug.Log("Decreasing: " + star.name + " radius: " + star.range);
    var counter = star.range;

    while (star.range >= 0f)
    {
        counter -= Time.deltaTime;
        star.range = counter;
        yield return null;
    }
    star.range = 0f;
}

IEnumerator ChooseStar()
{
    // Looks scary but is totally fine in Coroutines as long as you yield somewhere
    // instead of starting a new Coroutine simple continue the one you already have
    while (true)
    {
        var duration = Random.Range(3.0f, 8.0f);

        var choosenStar = stars[Random.Range(0, stars.Length)];

        // This starts the Increase routine on that star
        // and at the same time waits for it to finish!
        //
        // since we also wait until DecreaseRadius is done this means 
        // at any time only exactly 1 star is animated at the same time
        yield return IncreaseRadius(choosenStar, duration);
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution 2 - Filter the random

Alternatively as it looks like you **want** to allow parallel animations of the stars I would simply filter out the List of available stars (ones that are not currently animated) for getting the random range. Something like

```
public Light[] stars;

// Use a list for dynamically adding and removing items
private List<Light> availableStars = new List<Light>();

private void Start()
{
    // initialize the available list
    // copy the references from stars
    availableStars.AddRange(stars);

    StartCoroutine(ChooseStar());
}

private IEnumerator IncreaseRadius(Light star, float duration)
{
    Debug.Log("Increasing: " + star.name + " radius: " + star.range);

    // As soon as you start animating this star
    // remove it from the list of availables
    availableStars.Remove(star);

    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        star.range = counter;
        yield return null;
    }

    // Decreasing and at the same time wait for it to finish
    yield return DecreaseRadius(star);

    // when finished add the star again to the availables
    availableStars.Add(star);
}

private static IEnumerator DecreaseRadius(Light star)
{
    Debug.Log("Decreasing: " + star.name + " radius: " + star.range);
    var counter = star.range;

    while (star.range >= 0f)
    {
        counter -= Time.deltaTime;
        star.range = counter;
        yield return null;
    }
    star.range = 0f;
}

IEnumerator ChooseStar()
{
    // Looks scary but is totally fine in Coroutines as long as you yield somewhere
    while (true)
    {
        var duration = Random.Range(3.0f, 8.0f);

        // in case that currently all stars are being animated
        // simply wait until the next one becomes available again
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => availableStars.Count > 0);

        // Pick a random star from the availables instead
        var chosenStar = availableStars[Random.Range(0, availableStars.Count)];

        // this check becomes then actually redundant
        //if (chosenStar.range <= 0f)
        //{
        StartCoroutine(IncreaseRadius(chosenStar, duration));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `yield return IncreaseRadius();` do the same as `yield return StartCoroutine(IncreaseRadius());`?

Comment: @trollingchar Honestly I don't know .. never used that one before ... I think the difference is that a routine started by `yield return StartCoroutine(IncreaseRadius())` can be stopped by `StopCoroutine(IncreaseRadius())` while an `IEnumerator` run by `yield return IncreaseRadius()` can not be stopped from the outside. But yes despite of that I guess it does the same

Comment: That means, if I do not want to stop a coroutine early, then `StartCoroutine` call is redundant?

Comment: @trollingchar as said .. I don't know ^^ But since `yield return IncreaseRadius();` so far always did exactly what it should I'ld say yes.

Comment: After some testing, I confirm that you're right. Thank you, I didn't know this.

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed answere, i have learn a lot. I have tested your code but i'm having an error on  availableStars.AddRange(stars); it says NullreferenceException

Comment: Try now ,;) with `private List<Light> availableStars = new List<Light>();`